# SAP HANA Order by without TOP n

Tags: sql-order-by, hana

In a SAP HANA SQL calculation view,
I need to sort by date, if I use select TOP n the following code works perfectly, the same code without top n doesn't sort the result, Am I missing something?

```
SELECT TOP 5
MATNR,
MANDT,
DOCNO,
DELIVERYDATE,
MISSING,
MISSING_TYPE
FROM "TABLE"

ORDER BY DELIVERYDATE ;
```

Comment: one ugly hack would be to request TOP 3billion

Comment: There's too little information here. Show the example and enough information on the calculation view to reproduce the behaviour. Generally speaking, if the ORDER BY is not obeyed, that's a bug (and there had been bugs like this). So you may as well check with a current HANA revision.